# sqlite multi-table select that checks boolean value

Tags: sql, sqlite, multiple-tables

I'm not very good at joins with lots of tables, having trouble putting this into SQLite.  I have a database with these tables:

Feeds->Channels->RegionsChannels->Regions.

where Channels can have 0 or more connections to Regions through RegionsChannels.

Regions has a boolean field (0, 1) that indicates whether or not the user has enabled this region.

I want to get some fields from Feeds, say, Feeds.id and Feeds.title for all the feeds that contain channels that either have no connection to Regions or have a connection to Regions where Regions.selected = 1;

I tried joining all the tables together like this:

```
select feeds.feed_id, feeds.title
from feeds
    left outer join channels on feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id
    left outer join regions_channels on channels.channel_id = regions_channels.channel_id
    left outer join regions on regions_channels.region_id = regions.region_id
        and regions.selected = 1
group by feeds.feed_id
order by feeds.feed_id;
```

trying to get only the selected regions but it just gave me back all the feeds anyway.  I thought maybe I should be doing a RIGHT OUTER JOIN on the regions table but I'm using SQLite and it doesn't support RIGHT or FULL OUTER JOINs.

UPDATE:

I just tried this and I am getting exactly what I want, I have toggled several regions.selected and it comes back good every time.  But I have no idea if it REALLY works or if it just looks like works, because I don't understand how it is working:

```
select feeds.feed_id, feeds.title
from feeds
    left outer join channels on feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id
    left outer join regions_channels on channels.channel_id = regions_channels.channel_id
    left outer join regions on regions_channels.region_id = regions.region_id
where regions._id is NULL
    or regions.selected = 1
group by feeds.feed_id
order by feeds.feed_id;
```

this doesn't feel right to me but it works so i am using it for now...

Comment: Replace `regions.selected = 1` with `regions.selected IS 1`.

Comment: still gives me all the feeds

Comment: Replace `AND` with `WHERE`!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last `AND` was trimming `regions` table.

`regions.selected=1` must be on `WHERE`clause.

If you choose `NOT region.selected IS 0`, then all feeds not disabled will show up.

Replaced `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT` - IMO, it's more correct.

`LEFT` or `LEFT OUTER` is same in [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite).

```
SELECT DISTINCT feeds.feed_id, feeds.title
FROM feeds
    LEFT JOIN channels ON feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id
    LEFT JOIN regions_channels ON channels.channel_id = regions_channels.channel_id
    LEFT JOIN regions ON regions_channels.region_id = regions.region_id
WHERE NOT regions.selected IS 0
ORDER BY feeds.feed_id;
```

Comment: if I don't use GROUP BY I get a row for every channel, but I just want the feeds.  GROUP BY does that.

Comment: You have same feed in multiple channels?

Comment: there are multiple channels in each feed

Comment: that is to say, feed_id is the primary key in feeds and a foreign key in channels

Comment: I got it. I was misunderstanding schema. Corrected.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!  I like your where clause.  I actually forgot to mention that I need to sum() a column from the channels table, and if I use DISTINCT in that case it messes up the results. I will stick with group by in my case but I will remember to try to use DISTINCT in the future.

Answer (score 0):

By putting `selected = 1` into the join condition, you have told the database to return either records that match that condition, or (because of `OUTER`), to return columns filled with `NULL`.
You must put the condition into the `WHERE` clause so that it is checked *after* the join.

Second change: I've dropped the `LEFT OUTER` fropm the feeds/channels join because you did not say you wanted feeds that do not have channels.

```
SELECT feeds.feed_id, feeds.title
FROM feeds
JOIN channels ON feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id
LEFT JOIN regions_channels ON channels.channel_id = regions_channels.channel_id
LEFT JOIN regions on regions_channels.region_id = regions.region_id
WHERE regions.selected = 1
   OR regions.selected IS NULL
GROUP BY feeds.feed_id
ORDER BY feeds.feed_id
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation!  I arrived at the same place but I didn't understand why it worked.